# Use Connection string of Web.Config in ConnectionInfo

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, connection-string

I want to use connection string defined into Web.Config file into my Class code which is using `ConnectionInfo` keyword.

I have defined my connection string in Web.Config file as::

```
 <connectionStrings>
  <add name="Connection_Report" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.csdl|res://*/Model.ssdl|res://*/Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=servername;initial catalog=dbName;user id=username;password=password;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

And in my Class code I want to use it into `ConnectionInfo` 
Currently I have to define it in conroller as::

```
ConnectionInfo ConnInfo = new ConnectionInfo { ServerName = "servername", UserID = "UserID", Password = "Password", DatabaseName = "DatabaseName" };
```

But I want to use it from Connection string Defined into Web.Config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

will this help you:

```
var connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["yourConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);
        string dbName = builder.InitialCatalog;
        string dbDataSource = builder.DataSource;
        string userId = builder.UserID;
        string pass = builder.Password;
```

And then in your `ConnectionInfo`:

```
ConnectionInfo ConnInfo = new ConnectionInfo { ServerName = "dbDataSource", UserID = "userId", Password = "pass", DatabaseName = "dbName" };
```